# Why am I getting a recursion error when trying to create an object in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, compiler-errors

When I try to create and instantiate a custom object in Python, I keep receiving this error:

```
C:\Users\kyles\Documents\Repositories\Python\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/kyles/Documents/Repositories/Python/pythonProject1/homework_day2/oop/question 4.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Documents\Repositories\Python\pythonProject1\homework_day2\oop\question 4.py", line 158, in <module>
    person = Person("Kyle", "test", "987", "ert")
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Documents\Repositories\Python\pythonProject1\homework_day2\oop\question 4.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.__pname = pname
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Documents\Repositories\Python\pythonProject1\homework_day2\oop\question 4.py", line 25, in __pname
    self.__pname = new_name
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Documents\Repositories\Python\pythonProject1\homework_day2\oop\question 4.py", line 25, in __pname
    self.__pname = new_name
  File "C:\Users\kyles\Documents\Repositories\Python\pythonProject1\homework_day2\oop\question 4.py", line 25, in __pname
    self.__pname = new_name
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, pname, address, phone_number, email):
        self.__pname = pname
        self.__address = address
        self.__phone_number = phone_number
        self.__email = email

    @property
    def __pname(self):
        return self.__pname

    @__pname.setter
    def __pname(self, new_name):
        self.__pname = new_name

    @property
    def __address(self):
        return self.__address

    @__address.setter
    def __address(self, new_address):
        self.__address = new_address

    @property
    def __phone_number(self):
        return self.__phone_number

    @__phone_number.setter
    def __phone_number(self, new_number):
        self.__phone_number = new_number

    @property
    def __email(self):
        return self.__email

    @__email.setter
    def __email(self, new_email):
        self.__email = new_email

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(f'Class: {self}, Name: {self.__pname}')


person = Person("Kyle", "123 Main St", "1234567890", "email@website.com")
print(person)
```

I'm positive I coded everything correctly but for some reason, the object won't get created. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? I'm currently in the process of learning the OOP aspect of Python and was able to get similar code to work for a different program, but I'm totally stumped as to why this will not compile

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], I guess you'll find the error then. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: A property definition can't try to access the same attribute it's a property for. You need to use a different attribute name internally.